# Вывести по 3 строки, для каждой должности (2 таблицы: Сотрудники - Должности)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Помогите пожалуйста написать запрос MS SQL!
Вывести по 3 самых старших сотрудников для каждой должности.

Таблицы:

[Employee]
ID | NAME | AGE | POSITION_ID

[Positions]
ID | NAME (FK to Employee POSITION_ID)

Comment: фиддл с тестовыми данными то приложите тоже.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

можно пронумеровать строки по убыванию возраста в каждой группе (`row_number()`) и выбрать, где номера меньше трех

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT p.name as p, e.name as n, age
         , row_number() over (partition by p.id order by age desc) as rn
    FROM positions AS p
    INNER JOIN employee AS e ON ( e.position_id = p.id )
)
SELECT p, n, age
FROM data 
WHERE rn <= 3 
ORDER BY p, age DESC
```

Comment: Спасибо, братка, дай пятку

Answer (score 0):

Еще один вариант:

```sql
select a.name, a.age, b.name from 
  (select name, age, position_id
  from (select * from Employee order by position_id, age desc) x
  group by position_id) as a
inner join Positions as b on a.position_id = b.id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/81dc064/71